# Splunk search start / end time by a requestID

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I'm looking to calculate some timing metrics per company and API route using a request ID for the following log structure where the total elapsed time is defined as the timestamp of the the first entry with the requestId subtract the last entry of a requestId.

```
Entry 1 00:00:00 {company:"A",requestId:123, path:"/org"}
Entry 2 00:00:01: {company:"A",requestId:123}
Entry 3 00:00:01: {company:"B",requestId:111, path:"/org"}
Entry 4 00:00:05: {company:"B",requestId:111, url:...}
Entry 5 00:00:08: {company:"B",requestId:111, url:...}
Entry 6 00:00:10: {company:"B",requestId:111}
Entry 7 00:01:00: {company:"A",requestId:123, url:...}
Entry 8 00:02:00: {company:"A",requestId:123}
```

I would like to see the following for the /org path:

| Org | Avg | Min | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company A | .. | ... | ... |
| Company B | .. | ... | ... |

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the fields extracted, the `stats` command can compute average, minimum, and maximum times for each company and request ID.

````
index=foo
```Extract company and requestId fields```
| rex "company:\\\"(?<Org>[^\\\"]+)\\\",requestId:(?<requestId>\d+)"
```Compute the elapsed time (last timestamp - first timestamps) of each transaction```
| eventstats range(_time) as elapsedTime by Org, requestId
| stats avg(elapsedTime) as Avg, min(elapsedTime) as Min, max(elapsedTime) as Max by Org, requestId
| table Org Avg Min Max
````